# Are there any applications to manage SMS messaging on an Android from Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, android

I have an Android phone because I'm awesome. I would like to be more awesome though. I would like to be able to send and receive text messages (SMS/MMS/etc) from my desktop when I'm near it, mainly because it's faster and it means I don't have to fish around in my pocket every time it vibrates.

Samsung has an app called Kies Air which is basically a little web server you run on your phone and connect to via a desktop browser. Like most Samsung software I've had the displeasure of using, it's pap. Slow and unreliable. It also requires a certain amount of me pressing buttons on my phone to get working too, so less than ideal.

So I was wondering if there was a better solution out there for Ubuntu, ideally not requiring me to root the phone, that lets me manage, view and send messages.

Comment: I'm awesome too (Xperia X8) :) . You can try this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/android-app-to-send-and-receive-sms.html, works fine. It charges you :(

Comment: @Bruno Pable: This should be an answer.

Comment: Remote Desktop for Android will do this, but it's probably more complex that what you are looking for. Here's the market link: https://market.android.com/details?id=pl.androiddev.mobiletab#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwicGwuYW5kcm9pZGRldi5tb2JpbGV0YWIiXQ..

Comment: Google Voice is a simple way of doing this.  Install the Google Voice addon for your browser (Chrome?) and you can send/recieve SMS from your computer.  I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but it is a solution I have found more than effective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Airdroid, it does everything you want for free !
It is a webserver like KiesAir and very easy to operate SMS communications.

http://www.airdroid.com/

Comment: this is an amazing app

Comment: AirDroid isn't free software unfortunately; but many free software alternatives have sprung since then.

Comment: @Clément like what?

Comment: Today, I don't know.  Four years ago when I wrote the comment?  See the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

[Pushbullet](http://pushbullet.com) is a service that have a primary function as a bridge between your phone and browser. All notifications from phone gets to your desktop.

Now there are many more features, as calling or sending texts from desktop.

Explore their channels and many integrations that are made by community.

[image]

Comment: Apparently PushJet is a free software alternative.

Comment: PushJet looks like abandonware.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way - install [Desktop SMS](http://sites.google.com/site/desktopsmsforandroid/en)

Another simple way - [EasySMS](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-fireblade-easysms-pwzx.aspx) which sets up a web server (?) on yourAndroid and you then use its web interface to send SMSs from your machine.

Then there's telnet - if you root your phone, you can install a telnet daemon on it. You can then telnet to it from your PC, and send and sms using this command:

sms send

Comment: Both of these seem pretty stale / dead.

Answer (score 1):

Putting my vote in for texdro pro. It runs on all platforms as it's a Java app and does exactly what it says on the tin - send and view texts. Also has system notifications for newly received texts. The pro version cost is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be used for an android based cellphone but I have tested Wammu in the past in order to manage both sms/calendar and other useful features in several cellphones (Nokia and Motorola), which successfully does the work without a hassle, except for those cases when the data cable suffered of a sudden disconnection and stopped working because of a physical failure.

Check it out at [**[GW]ammu**](http://wammu.eu/) official website. A screenshot of the main interface is posted here for you to see Wammu in action.

[image]

Even when they don't say for Android based phones, I have seen over the net several attempts to work with Wammu in an Android based cellphone. And the official list of supported phones can be reached right here: http://wammu.eu/phones/

Samsungs can be reached right here: http://wammu.eu/phones/samsung/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Yate](http://yateclient.yate.ro/) (**Y**et **A**nother **T**elephony **E**ngine) is an Instant Messenger and a SoftPhone. Yate uses Google Voice among other telephony protocols. The Linux source for Yate can be downloaded from the link in the first sentence and installed by compiling the .tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Rambox https://rambox.pro/#pricing . It has "Android Messages" as well as many other apps. It has a free edition which is more than enough for most of use cases.