# Receive and Send SMS via PC

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop SMS client in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145772/desktop-sms-client-in-ubuntu)

I am very interested in using Ubuntu , but there is one question . Am I able to send and receive SMS via PC ?

Comment: Hi Leow, it is better to first search in askubuntu for your question before posting it: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=SMS

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77480/are-there-any-applications-to-manage-sms-messaging-on-an-android-from-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: This question should be phrased a but better. Think of Ask Ubuntu as a place were several people will see your question. It's not a forum or one on one format.  Try asking a more direct question or phrasing this question with a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mightytext][1]  to Send/Receive SMS from your computer or tablet

[1]: http://mightytext.net/ OR http://ezfreesms.com