How to send text to an Android phone from a computer running Ubuntu?
Is there a workable way to send text to my Android phone?
Text_T0_Phone.sh 2812994387 "https://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/top-exercises-belly-fat"
{"success":false,"error":"Sorry, free SMS are disabled for this country due to abuse."}~$

I would like a method with less steps than sending an email to my phone and having to copy the text in my message to my browser.
I have followed the instructions here to install KDE Connect on my phone and home computer.
When I click on Find Devices nothing happens.
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-kde-connect-ubuntu-16-04


You can achieve this by installing KDE Connect or GSConnect if you are using GNOME

VPN and spoof the location to have the server accept the request (if workable), however for lazily visiting URLs I'm browsing on my PC from my phone I usually copy the link and paste it into a QR code generator, then scan the code. Still a few steps but hey

(a simple free HTTP proxy would also likely work to spoof the location)

@Ajay I edited my post to show my O.S. ps -ef | grep gnome
andy        2663    2096  0 01:44 ?        00:00:01 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
andy        2701    2096  0 01:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --foreground --components=pkcs11,secrets --control-d

@Ajay please write that as an answer.

Related: send a file between an android phone and a computer with Ubuntu: See this link.

Try ntfy: https://ntfy.sh/

This question is similar to: Are there any applications to manage SMS messaging on an Android from Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Alternatively a similar duplication question that includes Ajay's suggestion in its answers has already been posted at Ask Ubuntu.

There are several ways in which you can achieve this:
Using KDE Connect:
KDE Connect lets you connect all the devices within the same wifi network. Install the application on your mobile device (whether it is Android or iOS) and install the Linux software from their Download page.
It has many features like Remote control, send clipboard, presentation mode, Run command, file transfer, etc. I have used this application and it shares my copied text from Ubuntu to my Android phone instantly when I copy on the system itself. On Android, you have to share the copied text, select the KDE Connect app, and then select your device to get that text.

Using GSConnect:
It is a GNOME extension that implements the KDE Connect protocol where you don't have to install the software to achieve the same. You still have to install the KDE Connect application on your mobile device. You will even be able to access several features within the control panel. I am using this extension, which provides all the features provided by KDE Connect.

Using websites:
Several websites will transfer files within the same network without any internet. One such website is Snapdrop which will allow you to share your text and send files. You don't have to install and configure any application on any device by this method.


Please add the same answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/77480/are-there-any-applications-to-manage-sms-messaging-on-an-android-from-ubuntu. The existing answers there don't mention KDE Connect

@ArchismanPanigrahi This existing answer to that question features GSConnect, but it only mentions that you need to install KDE connect on the Android phone, so anything that's not specifically about KDE Connect on Ubuntu would be a duplicate answer if it was posted there.

@Ajay I installed KDE connect on my phone and computer. When I start KDE connect, it finds no devices. And the phone version says No devices.

From your question I understand that you want to use a SMS gateway, ie. an online service that allows sending text messages to mobile phones from the Internet - and the service you are using is rejecting your request.
There is no single, foolproof method of doing this. Depending on your phone provider and country, there may or may not exist gateways that will allow you to send a message. Some phone providers may offer such gateways on their own websites. Your phone provider is always the first place to look for such things. There are also third-party gateways, but they are generally subscription-based and paid.
Try to google for "SMS gateway", adding the name of your provider and country to search query, then look over the found websites, check their terms and conditions of use, and maybe you'll find a site that will work. There is no guarantee. The situation in this area is very dynamic and a gateway that worked a few years ago (which is probably used by your script "Text_T0_Phone.sh") may not exist anymore.
Here is one such service that I was using once; it is paid but offers free trial, which may be enough for you: https://www.world-text.com/
There is also another possibility - you need to buy an USB cellular modem, capable of sending and receiving of text messages, connect it to your computer and use software like Wammu to send messages from the modem to your phone.
